# Accessing the value of a control in a form array in angular2

Tags: angular, typescript

Am setting my form via form builder with an array of a rest api result

This is my form builder code

```
 this._inspectionService.getChecklists(this.truckParam)
  .subscribe(
    res=> {
      this.checklists = res;
      let inspectionform: FormGroup;
      let checkinputs: FormArray = new FormArray([]);
      for (let i = 0; i < this.checklists.length; i++) {
        checkinputs.push(
          new FormGroup({
            description:new FormControl(this.checklists[i].item),
            input: new FormControl(''),
            yesradio: new FormControl(''),
            noradio: new FormControl(''),
          })
        )
      }

      this.inspectionform = this._formBuilder.group({
        inputfileds: this._formBuilder.array(checkinputs.controls)
      })

    },
  );
```

Now in my form

```
<form [formGroup]="inspectionform">

<ion-card *ngFor='let checklists of inspectionform.controls["inputfileds"]["controls"] 
 ;let i=index'>

//at this stage i can access
{{checklists.controls["description"].value}} //it retuns a value

//NOW AM trying to connect the form control inputs via

  <ion-input type="text" formControlName='checklists.controls["noradio"]'>
IVE ALSO TRIED
  <ion-input type="text" formControlName='checklists.controls.noradio'>
```

And the error returned is

```
Cannot find control with name: 'checklists.controls["noradio"]'
```

Where am i going wrong

Comment: Is inputfileds misspelt in your code as well or just here?

Anyway, try formControlName='{{checklists.controls["noradio"].value}}' ...

Comment: Isn't it inspectionform.controls['']...

Comment: No its not misspelt on the form builder i actually put it as inputfileds

Comment: But accessing the FormBuilder object with controls, which is assigned to `inspectionform` so why not try `inspectionform.control['inputfileds]['noradio']` since you're adding it to that builder.

Comment: #wesside am looping through the array of controls as from <ion-card *ngFor='let checklists in the question thats why ive called checklists

Comment: Well, there is no form control with a name of "checklists.controls["noradio"]", it would bind with `[formControl]="checklists.controls['noradio']"` though.

Comment: The control is there because when i try accessing {{checklists.controls["description"].value}} this returns a value which can only return if ...checklists.controls["description"] ...is a control

Comment: #slintesod thanks your solution worked [formControl]="checklists.controls['noradio']"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no form control with a name of "checklists.controls["noradio"]", it would bind with `[formControl]="checklists.controls['noradio']"` however because then it attaches directly to the control object. `[formControlName]="'noradio'"` might also work but FormArray access and control is not my strong suit.

The syntax between the two is different enough that it warrants [further reading](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/FormControlName-directive.html).

Comment: what of radio buttons what should i use to bind since binding with formControl causes both to be checked

Comment: Per HTML radio buttons are grouped by `name` and then made distinct by their `value`:

http://plnkr.co/edit/PnEheiI0NB6BYq229CLR?p=preview

Comment: @GEOFFREYMWANGI to get your attention because I forgot it in my first comment.